# How to display the calendar of the current month in F#?

Tags: f#

I would like to display the calendar of the current month using F# ( something similar to Linux command 'cal' ). Is there a native way of doing it in F# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is any standard function that will print a current calendar to a console. However, you can easily get the information you need to print that on your own:

```
open System
open System.Globalization

// Get information about calendar for the current cultural settings
let cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar
let now = DateTime.Now

// Get days in month from the curretn calendar
for d in 1 .. cal.GetDaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month) do
  // Create date time and print the date together with a day of week
  let dt = DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, d)
  printfn "%s %A" (dt.ToShortDateString()) dt.DayOfWeek
```

You could use `dt.DayOfWeek` to align the output nicely, just like what `cal` does on Linux.

Alternatively, if you have some UI, you could use `DateTimePicker` type from Windows Forms (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx)) or a bit nicer `Calendar` control for WPF (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx)). The WinForms control works in F# interactive too:

```
open System.Windows.Forms

let frm = new Form(Visible=true)
frm.Controls.Add(new DateTimePicker())
```